# Converting .MOV audio files to Text

Tags: speech-to-text, quicktime

I have couple of audio files in the `.mov` format. Is there any software available which can convert the speech/lecture/conversation in that audio file into text?

Answer (score 0):

You'll do your best in searching for speech-to-text or transcriber engines.  [gAudi](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0CCoQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogleblog.blogspot.com%2F2008%2F09%2Fgoogle-audio-indexing-now-on-google.html&ei=AEWGTc-ILMS30gGmyrjgCA&usg=AFQjCNGndm12oMV_EC2pZLtnXgYdAOjzIw) (Google's Audio) a now-defunct Labs project, worked on indexing videos based on their audio.

If you find some info, I'm sure posting it here would help some users.